# Passing a return statement as a parameter of another function

Tags: python

I've looked at 10 of these answers and cannot find the answer, maybe I am asking the wrong question but what I am trying to do is take a dictionary created in fileToDict and use it as the parameter of dictValueTotal to add all the values of the dictionary and return that value (which will be used in a third function). Yes, this is indeed homework but I would like to understand it as I am new to python and really don't get how to pass the return value into another function and can't find an answer online or in the book we are using this I don't want to create a class for it as we haven't covered it in class (see what I did there?). Thanks in advance!

Errors being received: First I was getting no global variable 'd' defined so I added the dictionary = fileToDict("words1.txt") line but now I am getting the error TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Almost forgot my words1.txt looks like this with each string/integer on a separate line:
    the 231049254

```
cat 120935
hat 910256
free 10141

one 9503490
we 102930
was 20951
#

going 48012
to 1029401
program 10293012
    he 5092309
```

And this is the code manipulating it:

```
import sys

def dictValueTotal (dictionary):
    """dictValueTotal takes in a dictionary and outputs the sum of all the values of the different keys in the input dictionary"""
    valueTotal = sum(dictionary.values)
    return valueTotal


def fileToDict (inFile):
    """takes a name of a file as input and outputs a dictionary containing the contents of that file"""
    fileIn = open(inFile, "r")           #Open a file
    d = {}                           #create a dictionary
    for line in fileIn:
            line = line.strip()          #remove whitespace
            if line == "":               #disregard empty strings
                    continue
            if line[0] == '#':           #disregard lines starting with #
                    continue
            print line                   #debugging purposes
            line = line.split()          #remove duplicated spaces
            print line                   #debugging purposes
            line[1] = int(line[1])
            print line                   #debugging purposes
            key = line[0]
            value = line[1]
            d[key] = value
    print d
    return d
def main():
    fileToDict("words1.txt")
    dictionary = fileToDict("words1.txt")
    dictValueTotal(dictionary)


main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values` is a method.  You need to call it.  use `dictionary.values()` (note the parentheses), not `dictionary.values`.

Comment: perfect thank you so much! I was wondering why it wasn't working since I was doing it the same way I was taught in class much appreciated BrenBarn